# Issue with a DIV not showing

Tags: html, css

Any idea why my div "conference-shape" (.conferences-shape) DIV doesn't show up under the "Personal Trainer / coaching DIV" blue label DIV (.espace-coaching-shape) in the header of the page? See http://goo.gl/7Ki6Rs

Many thanks

CSS:

```
.espace-nutrition-shape {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
    clear: both;
  width: 455px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 125px;
     height: 0;
  border-top: solid 55px #114191;
  border-left: solid 55px transparent;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.espace-coaching-shape {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  clear: both;

  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*background-color: #1655bf;*/
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 55px #1655bf;
  border-left: solid 55px transparent;
  width: 515px;
 cursor: pointer;


}

    .conferences-shape {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      clear: both;
      width: 350px;
      height: 55px;
      margin-top: 20px;
       height: 0;
      border-top: solid 55px #236ce5;
      border-left: solid 55px transparent;
       cursor: pointer;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="espace-nutrition-shape wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="1s">
                <a class="text-shape-accueil" href="cabinet-de-nupie.html">Conseils nutritionnels</a>
            </div>

            <div class="espace-coaching-shape wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="2s">
                <a class="text-shape-accueil" href="personal-trainer">Personal Training / coaching</a>
            </div>

            <div class="conferences-shape wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="3s">
                <a class="text-shape-accueil" href="biographie.html">Conférences</a>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML here as well instead of a link to your website.

Comment: You should definitely show your HTML. Inspect element says nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I've added it. You can also see the page live here: http://goo.gl/7Ki6Rs

Comment: Add the class `.espace-coaching-shape` and it works. Looks like `.conferences-shape` is not a defined CSS class.

Comment: ssergei, the .conferences-shape is defined in his CSS. Applying .espace-coaching-shape works, but it has different width, so he needs to use .conferences-shape class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not picking up the `.conferences-shape` class. I've run the css through a validator http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fblondiau.lu%2Fcss%2Fstyles.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en and it could be due to the way you have commented `/* End accuei popup contact form */ */`

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue indeed!

Comment: I checked this as well and it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
.conferences-shape {
position: relative;
float: right;
clear: both;
height: 55px;
margin-top: 20px;
border-top: solid 55px #1655bf;
border-left: solid 55px transparent;
width: 350px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Replace the whole class with this. This should work.